# Solving numerically unstable integration in R

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration, infinity

I have a function which I would like to integrate for `x` between `-Inf` and `Inf`. I'm using the function `integrate` in R. However, I do get an error saying `Non-finite function value`.

```
test_func<-function(x,t,A,sigma, y){
  
  n1 = exp(-((y - x)^2)/(4 * sigma * t)) + exp(-((y + x)^2)/(4 * sigma * t))
  d1 = sqrt(4 * pi * sigma * t)
  a2 = 2 * A /(sigma) * exp((4 * A *(y + x +(4 * A * t)))/(sigma))
  b2 = pracma::erfc(((y + x)+(8 * A * t))/(2 * sqrt(sigma * t)))
  res = (n1/d1) - (a2 * b2)
  return(res)
}

t<-1000
A<-0.01
sigma<-1
y<-1

integrate(test_func,lower = -Inf , upper = Inf, t,A,sigma,y)$value
```

And I do get the following error:

```
Error in integrate(test_func, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, t, A, sigma,  : 
  non-finite function value
```

I know that there ways to make such type of integration numerically stable, but I have no idea, which one could help in this case.

Comment: For `x > 17703.5` the expression `exp(4 * A *(y + x +(4 * A * t)))` is infinite and `b2` is cannot be made small enough to compensate for this. Please check your functions before applying integration, optimization, or other routines to it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But what do you mean exactly by 'check your function'? The function is correctly written. Are you sugegesting to not integrate between -Inf and Inf, but instead using an interval between -17703.5 and 17703.5?

Comment: You will have to realize that (1) numerical integration over infinite domains is problematic anyway and has to be done with care, and (2) in floating point double precision your function is *not* correct. Multiplying two terms, where one is going to `Inf` and the other to zero, will lead to largely unpredictable results. Maybe you can rewrite the function to avoid this erratic behavior. I assume that using multiple-precision will not eliminate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree and this is why I posted the question. I was wondering whether other people may have more experience with this kind of issues and suggest a possible solution. In another example I had used the following procedure a *b = exp(log(a )+ log(b)) to solve a similar problem. But in this case, it does not work.